# Duplicate a row under a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this following input DataFrame df

```
input df

  Name   Number B2B     Number B2C
   Pa       1               0
   Co       2               1
   Pa       1               1
```

I want to duplicate rows only if Number B2B and Number B2C are both different from zero and then modify df in order to have only one value for each row is different from zero

```
Out put: df
 Name   Number B2B     Number B2C
   Pa      1               0
   Co      2               0
   Co      0               1
   Pa      1               0
   Pa      0               1
```

Comment: You can also define a kernel `k = [[1,0],[0,1]]` and multiple each row which satisfies the condition above to get the 2 values on its diagonals. So, `[2,1]*k` becomes `[[2,0], [0,1]]`. Check my approach on how to do that while retaining your indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Here is a shorter way to do the same as below. The difference is, this expands each row into 2 rows initially then drops the ones that are not needed, unlike the latter approach which selects which to expand first, based on if condition, then expands them.

```
k = [[1,0], 
     [0,1]]

out = df.apply(lambda row: row.values*k, axis=1).explode()
out = pd.DataFrame(out.to_list(), columns=df.columns, index=out.index)
out = out[~(out==0).all(1)].reset_index()
out
```

```
  Name  Number B2B  Number B2C
0   Pa           1           0
1   Co           2           0
2   Co           0           1
3   Pa           1           0
4   Pa           0           1
```

---

Here is an elegant way to do this. Try this method -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Pa','Co','Pa'],'Number B2B':[1,2,1], 'Number B2C':[0,1,1]})

idx_cols = ['Date', 'ID', 'Name', 'Quantity Type', 'Type_B', 'Type_C', 'Description']

df.set_index(idx_cols)
#Set 'Name' as index
df = df.set_index(idx_cols)

#kernel to shift values to diagonals
k = [[1,0], 
     [0,1]]

#if all values in row are non zero, multiply with k else return row values with added axis
f = lambda row: row.values*k if (row!=0).all() else row.values[None,:]

#apply on 3 rows and explode to get 5 rows instead of 3
out = df.apply(f, axis=1).explode()

#convert to dataframe with separate columns, col names and index values
out2 = pd.DataFrame(out.to_list(), columns=df.columns, index=out.index).reset_index()
print(out2)
```

```
  Name  Number B2B  Number B2C
0   Pa           1           0
1   Co           2           0
2   Co           0           1
3   Pa           1           0
4   Pa           0           1
```

Explanation -

1. First, create a kernel `k = [[1,0],[0,1]]`. Multiplying this with a row, will shift the individual values to the diagonals. So, `[2,1]*k` becomes `[[2,0], [0,1]]`
2. Then a lambda function checks whether each row has both values as nonzero using `(x!=0).all()`
3. The tertiary operator basically says, `if both values are nonzero, then multiply this with kernel, else, just return it as it is`.
4. The `.explode()` changes the 3 rows to 5 rows, each with 2 length lists.
5. Finally, you take this series which contains these 2 length lists (now 5 rows instead of 3) and converts them into separate columns with same column names in a dataframe. You can also set the index to the index from previous step because index are retained even after the apply.

---

**NOTE:** If you want to add more columns, only difference would be to expand the kernel size. You can either manually define it, but a better way would be to simply use -

```
k = np.eye(df.shape[0])
```

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Make sure to use this after the `df.set_index('Name')`, to avoid incorrect kernel size.

Comment: What if I want also to include a third column for example instead of Number B2B and Number B2C, I'll take into consideration a third column that calls Number B2L. In this case, I should put `k=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]` ?

Comment: You can, instead of explicitly making the kernel, just use `k = np.eye(df.shape[0])` after setting `name` as index. This would give you the identity kernel with the shape of the number of columns X number of columns, which is what you need.

Comment: Well, I don't prefer to set name as an index because my real dataframe has a lot of categorical columns, and I want to do all this operations based only on two columns

Comment: Oh, in that case you can just pick up the columns that you want to perform this operation on,put them into a dataframe,  and then run the code to create a new dataframe. The after that use `pd.concat` to horizontally combine the 2 data frames

Comment: Either ways, you will have to select which columns to expand and which not to. All other approaches need you to do the same as well. Maybe just create 2 lists. `expand_cols`, and `idx_cols` from the original dataframe's `df.columns`? That way you can simply do `df.set_index(idx_cols)` and retain the indexes after all the operations are done.

Comment: Well, I tried 'the elegant method' on only two columns (B2B and B2C) however the number of rows didn't duplicate

Comment: I have created the dataframe df exactly the way you have posted. in the code example. can you run the whole thing and see? run it separately .

Comment: I am able to run both the methods and get the expected output exactly same as your expected one.

Comment: Yes it worked! However, what can I do to add the two selected columns to the original one especially that In reality I have 10 columns ?

Comment: hmm could you add an example of that maybe? say maybe with 2 columns? Or better yet, just tell me the column names `df.columns`

Comment: In the initial dataFrame I have the following columns: `Date`, `ID`, `Name`, `Quantity` `Type`, `Number B2B`, `Number B2C`, `Type_B`, `Type_C`, `Description`. In order to use your method I created a new dataframe called df1 that has only `Name`, `Number` `B2B`, `Number B2C` and then applied your method. Now, I want to create a new DataFrame with all columns and duplicated rows obtained

Comment: I have updated my code. let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Try the second part, where i import numpy and pandas.

Comment: I had an error that tells me that operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (2,2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228592/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-chloe).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following your logic:

```
# identify those with both non-zero
nonzeros = df[df.ne(0).all(1)]

# duplicate those rows
out = pd.concat([df, nonzeros])

# first in pair will have B2B=0
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(keep='first'), 'Number B2B'] = 0

# second in pair will have B2C = 0
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(keep='last'), 'Number B2C'] = 0

# sort by index so the duplicate rows are next to each other
out = out.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Number B2B  Number B2C
0           1           0
1           2           0
2           0           1
3           1           0
4           0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to achieve with `concat()` and masks

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   Number B2B     Number B2C
     1               0
     2               1
     1               1
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

pd.concat([
    df[df.eq(0).any(axis=1)],  # keeps rows where any value is zero
    df[~df.eq(0).any(axis=1)].assign(**{"Number B2B":0}),  # duplicate, set B2B to 0
    df[~df.eq(0).any(axis=1)].assign(**{"Number B2C":0}),  # duplicate, set B2C to 0
]).reset_index(drop=True)
```